# iPhone calls are way too loud

Tags: iphone, audio, sound-volume, call

Some people I call via iPhone 7 (iOS 14.4.1) are just way too loud. I turn the volume all the way down and it is still very loud.

When I search online, all suggestions are for making it louder or for reducing the volume of music with the equalizer of the music app.

Is there any way to make it less loud, besides buying some external volume control?

And am I the only one who gets blasted by the volume of some calls?

Comment: I usually can't turn the volume far enough up. You know that the volume control only affects caller volume whilst you're actually on a call? The same button presses affect different things depending on what the phone is doing at the time - ringer, music playback, call volume etc.

Comment: *Some people I call via iPhone are just way too loud. I turn the volume all the way down and it is still very loud.* - The earpiece and speaker have different settings. You always have to turn it down separately. The ringtone and audio playback of, for example, music are also dealt with separately.